# Windows Server Physical Connection

Tags: topology

Im new here and just starting to learn about windows server, i'm very curious to   know regarding the physical topology of a server based network (windows), lets say i want to install a complete feature of a windows server, what would be the physical connection be look like?
  I made a sample diagram but do not know if its correct. Hope you can enlighten me up. thank you.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about servers and applications are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a home network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would go modem > firewall/router > switch > server/workstations.

All of the workstations and servers would be plugged into the switch.

Comment: Indeed. Never use Windows(tm) as a router. That's never worked out well for anyone.

Comment: does it mean that the best setup would to let the router manage dns and dchp, and just install active directory /AD to the server?

Comment: If you install AD and want a functioning domain, the server with handle DNS (it installs DNS as part of installing AD). You just want a router/firewall to do the routing and to be the default gateway for the server and clients.